# XFCE 4.12: desktop taking ages to appear when dual monitor is on

Tags: gentoo, xfce

i'm using an Gentoo (3.18.9 / Graphic card: ATI  Trinity Radeon HD 7660D, details below) with XFCE 4.12 on top. Note that i'm to help isolate the problem, i'm not using any login manager, i'm logging from console and then running "startx".

If i start with one monitor, then log in and add the second, XFCE does a great job at configuring it, deciding which one is primary, and everything works fine.

However, if I then restart (with both monitor on), they both start in mirror mode up to the login, i login ok, then "startx", and i'm then seeing a sort of white screen with the cursor waiting, for nearly 2 minutes. Ultimately the desktop appears on both screen with the correct dual monitor setting. But there's obviously something wrong happening during those 2 minutes every time I open start XFCE.

Unfortunately I don't have many logs. The /var/log/* don't log anything, just the fact that I correctly logged in.

the Xorg in my home directory have a bit more stuff but no obvious error message. In a nutshell, if I try to compare those between a start with one screen, and a start with 2 screens, i have similar sequence, with one extra section when starting with 2 screens:

```
[    94.961] (II) RADEON(0): EDID for output HDMI-0
[    94.961] (II) RADEON(0): Manufacturer: ACI  Model: 2493  Serial#: 16843009
[    94.961] (II) RADEON(0): Year: 2014  Week: 50
[    94.961] (II) RADEON(0): EDID Version: 1.3
(...)
```

The two outputs identified as follow:

```
[    95.049] (II) RADEON(0): Output HDMI-0 using initial mode 1920x1080
[    95.049] (II) RADEON(0): Output DVI-0 using initial mode 1920x1080
```

Then here is the big timelag (see the timestamps jump):

```
[    95.290] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "KB USB Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[    95.290] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    95.290] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc104"
[    95.290] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   153.096] (II) RADEON(0): EDID vendor "ACI", prod id 9363
[   153.096] (II) RADEON(0): Using EDID range info for horizontal sync
[   153.096] (II) RADEON(0): Using EDID range info for vertical refresh
[   153.096] (II) RADEON(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   153.096] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
```

While in with one screen I have:

```
[   147.475] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "KB USB Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[   147.475] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   147.475] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc104"
[   147.475] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   148.151] (II) RADEON(0): EDID vendor "ACI", prod id 9363
[   148.151] (II) RADEON(0): Using EDID range info for horizontal sync
[   148.151] (II) RADEON(0): Using EDID range info for vertical refresh
```

I have tried asking on the XFCE forum and elsewhere and couldn't find any help... so this is pretty much my last try before I need to do more drastic changes (like moving to Gnome)...

So any help is appreciated (maybe even just to add extra-logging if that's feasible).

```
Config:
(--) RADEON(0): Chipset: "ARUBA" (ChipID = 0x9901)
...
(II) Module exa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    94.757]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 2.6.0
[    94.757]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
```

Comment: I would consider trying the Gentoo forum. It is a good question though. I have not tried multiple monitors on my Gentoo system.

Comment: Have you tried to monitor this using something really simple like twn or openbox? Just to be sure it's related to a DE (here Xfce)